# Checkbox disappears after submit

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to display my checked boxes after clicking the submit button. But my jquery script will hide the checked divs.

I would like to display the checked div even after submitting the form.

This is my HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<br />
<div id="myDiv">
<input class="check_app" type="checkbox" />
<input class="check_app2" type="checkbox" />
<input class="check_app3" type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div class="hide">blabla</div>

<div class="hide2">
Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Donec sed odio dui. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.
</div>
<br />
<button id="submitbutton" type="submit" name="action" value="submit">Send in Request</button> 
</form>
```

My Jquery

```
$('.check_app').change(function() {
 if ($(this).attr("checked")) {

    $('.hide').fadeIn();
    return;
 }
 $('.hide').fadeOut();
});

$('.check_app2').change(function() {
 if ($(this).attr("checked")) {

    $('.hide2').fadeIn();
    return;
 }
 $('.hide2').fadeOut();
});
```

CSS Below

```
.hide, .hide2 {
  display: none;
}
```

You can view the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/SolidSmash/7W8Up/

Any help would be great!


***Sorry if my question is not clear. But I will try to explain it in detail below:***

1. I have couple of checkboxes within my form
2. These checkboxes trigger a div (e.g. class="hide") to display (normally these divs are hidden)
3. When a checkbox is selected and the submit button is clicked, the displayed div will disappear (fade out).

I would like to keep the div after the submit if it was triggered by the checkbox.

Comment: If you want them to be visible just remove the `.fadeOut();` part of both functions? But your question is very unclear. 1. There is no submit handler in the script. 2. What is a "checked div"?

Comment: Ok so, tell me if i am wrong. You tagged PHP so i assume what you want to do is when the page reload, the checked `div` remain checked and the `p` is showed?

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon : That's exactly what I'm trying to do. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean that:

If the user checks one or more checkboxes, then clicks on submit and is returned to the page, after server-side processing, you want those same checkboxes to be selected and their respective DIVs being displayed?

If so, a couple approaches you can take:

1 - determine the checkboxes that are checked, server-side, when the form/page is posted to the server, and don't apply the .hide, .hide2, etc. classes to their respective DIVs - based on the checked checkboxes - on the way back down.

2 - inject a little bit of inline JavaScript on the way back down that triggers clicks for the checkboxes that were checked. Lets assume checkbox with class="check_app2" was checked prior to submit being clicked. Then, server-side, determine which checkboxes were checked (in this case the one with class="check_app2") inject some script like:

```
$(".check_app2").trigger("click");
```

The reason for #2 is so that you would get the DIVs fading in once the page is loaded. Don't set the checked state of the checkboxes server-side.

I would also change your Change handlers to be more generic and reusable, you're repeating yourself.

Some additional code for your reference. I'm not saying this is ideal code, just something for you to work from. Unfortunately, I've not used PHP, so can't offer any code to work from on that front.

HTML

```
<input data-div-class="hide" class="check_app" type="checkbox" />
<input data-div-class="hide2" class="check_app2" type="checkbox" />
<input class="check_app3" type="checkbox" />
```

jQuery

```
function Checkbox_OnChange() {
    var divClass = $(this).data("div-class");
    $("div."+divClass).fadeToggle();
}
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", Checkbox_OnChange);
$(".check_app2").trigger("click");
```

View the above working here: http://jsfiddle.net/emgee/pYH8S/

:)

Comment: Thanks for your response, emgee. Your suggestion seems very interesting. I will post the final code if it's working :).

Comment: I can't have two or more input fields with the same "data-div-class" with the jQuery function above. Because it keeps toggling. Please take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/SolidSmash/pYH8S/1/

Comment: @Twana: Very true. You'd need to have unique class name for each div, which means you'd likely want to assign each div a unique ID attribute instead. Then change data-div-class on your input checkboxes to data-div-id (or something appropriate) and use that value to target the div you want to toggle. Or you could look at something like I've shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/emgee/pYH8S/5/ and use positioning. Depends on your situation and what you're working with as to what makes sense and doesn't cause you headaches down the road. Just some ideas and code reference for you. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

My form is working :)

How?
1.I utilized the following code by emgee to clean up my previous js script (the old one is working fine though, but is quite heavy to use):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Checkbox_OnChange() {
var divClass = $(this).data("div-class");
$("div."+divClass).fadeToggle();
}
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", Checkbox_OnChange);

</script>
```

2.Added the following code (with PHP) on the triggered div to generate an inline css.

```
<?php if ((isset($services)) && (in_array("My Service", $services))) { echo 'style="display:block"'; } ?>
```

The PHP generates ***style="display: block;*** if the checkbox is set after the form processing.

So in my case:

```
<div class="hide2" <?php if ((isset($services)) && (in_array("My Service", $services))) { echo 'style="display:block"'; } ?>>
  Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. 
  Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.
</div>
```

*This isn't the best solution, but it works fine.*